# Artifactory/JFrog is producing the wrong parent artifactId in generated POM

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml, artifactory

I have encountered a strange bug while trying to deploy new release builds to my company's JFrog.io (fka: ArtifactoryOnline.com) repository. The project I'm working on has multiple maven modules, all under a single parent. When I upload the JAR files that maven builds to JFrog, the generated POM file is being populated with the incorrect parent artifactId.

I spent a great deal of time and could not find any problems with my company's codebase for the project, so I decided if I could reproduce the error from scratch. Thus I made [this throwaway project](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B6gJvA_y0mMpVDBGenVoNncyWWc) to demonstrate the bug. For those uninterested in downloading the full project, here are the relevant POM files:

The parent POM, "blueberry":

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.nbyrd</groupId>
    <artifactId>blueberry</artifactId>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <modules>
        <module>blueberryjam</module>
        <module>berries</module>
    </modules>
</project>
```

Dependant POM 1: "berries":

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <parent>
        <artifactId>blueberry</artifactId>
        <groupId>org.nbyrd</groupId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </parent>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <artifactId>berries</artifactId>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Dependant POM 2, "berry-jam":

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <parent>
        <artifactId>blueberry</artifactId>
        <groupId>org.nbyrd</groupId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </parent>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <artifactId>blueberry-jam</artifactId>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.nbyrd</groupId>
            <artifactId>berries</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

(For what it's worth, all of these POM files were generated in their entirety by JetBrains IntelliJ.)

Pretty straight forward at this point: I have two Maven modules--"berries" and "berry-jam"--that are housed under a central parent module, "blueberry". berry-jam uses berries as a dependency, although I'm not sure if that's relevant to the problem.

When I build the project, I get two JAR files: `berries-1.0.jar` and `berry-jam-1.0.jar`. This is as expected. At this point, I would upload these artifacts to Artifactory so that other projects may reference them. And this is where the trouble starts.
When I upload `berries-1.0.jar`, Artifactory generates the following POM file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://    maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <parent>
        <artifactId>berries</artifactId>
        <groupId>org.nbyrd</groupId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </parent>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <artifactId>berries</artifactId>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

As you can see, the generated POM defines the parent artifactId as "berries", which is wrong.
The same problem occurs when I upload `berry-jam-1.0.jar`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://    maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <parent>
        <artifactId>blueberry-jam</artifactId>
        <groupId>org.nbyrd</groupId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </parent>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <artifactId>blueberry-jam</artifactId>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.nbyrd</groupId>
            <artifactId>berries</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

In both cases, I would expect the parentId to be "blueberry", as it is explicitly stated in both of the child-modules' POM files. These incorrect artifactIds make it impossible to use these libraries. If a third-party application attempts to use these libraries, maven will produce the following warning when downloading dependencies and the build will fail:

> [WARNING] The POM for org.nbyrd:berries:jar:1.0 is invalid, transitive dependencies (if any) will not be available, enable debug logging for more details

This functionality used to work correctly in the past when uploading to Artifactory, so I'm not sure if something has changed in how the tool works or if I have simply done something wrong. Any thoughts?

Comment: What do you mean by `I would upload these artifacts to Artifactory so that other projects may reference them.`? Does this mean you have uploaded them manually ? Or have used your Maven build via `mvn deploy`?

Comment: @khmarbaise I upload them by logging in to jfrog.io and upload the artifacts into the appropriate repos, via my browser. I have not tried using `mvn deploy` before.

Comment: @khmarbaise Thanks for bringing up `mvn deploy`. I configured my project with `distributionManagement` settings and gave it a spin and now the artifacts are deployed correctly. So, at least I'm unblocked, but I still wonder why it would be a problem with the webapp version of deployment.

Comment: I did meet the same problem and have no idea about what is the hell happening~

Comment: Happened to me as well! So weird there is no straight answer!

Answer (score 1):

When you use `mvn deploy` maven deploys the `pom.xml`file  as separated artifact. But when you uploads the jar file with artifactory's web ui and asks artifactory to generate the pom file, I guess it generates it from the data presents in the jar. So the artifactory isn't aware about existing of a parent project.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem and my guess was that artifactory is trying to fix pom by changing first artifactId value it can find. Not seeing that it's inside parent node.

So I moved parent node below artifactId/version and that worked for me.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://    maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <artifactId>berries</artifactId>
    <version>2.0</version>
    <parent>
        <artifactId>berries</artifactId>
        <groupId>org.nbyrd</groupId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </parent>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```